# Can I use VPC Link to NLB with ACM private certificate?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, nlb, aws-certificate-manager, sslengine

I've got an AWS API GW that I'm trying to hook up to HTTPS REST endpoints in a different VPC.  According to AWS support and the docs I've ready the solution is to use a VPC link pointing to an NLB in the GWs VPC with IP targets in the other VPC.  My NLB is HTTPS since the backend services are HTTPS.  For the NLB SSL certificate I used ACM to generate a private certificate (based on an ACM private CA).  When I test the GW, I get the dreaded **General SSLEngine problem** error.  The NLB is working fine, I can hit it from my browser and get data back from the back-end services.  Does the VPC link not trust private certificates? I don't see any way to add CAs. This whole arrangement seems very convoluted to me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and after many tests found the root of the problem in the documentation of the API-Gateway. Basically, API-Gateway will not work with any certificates derived from the ACM's Private CAs. This is a list of all valid CAs to use with the API-Gateway:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-supported-certificate-authorities-for-http-endpoints.html